# The rank of a certain linear combination of mutually commuting nilpotent matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, nilpotent-matrices

Let $A_1,\ldots,A_r$ be mutually commuting $n\times n$ nilpotent matrices over $\mathbb C$, the field of complex numbers. For any complex number $c$, let $A(c):=A_0+cA_1+c^2A_2+\ldots +c^rA_r$. We assume that $\text{rk }A_1>\text{rk }A_0$. I expect that the rank of $A(c)$ to be at least as big as the rank of $A_1$ for all but finitely many values of $c$. Is this known to be either true or false? Note that, the nilpotency of the matrices as well as their commutativity is supposed to play a crucial role here. For if we take $A_0$ to be the $2\times 2$ upper triangular nilpotent matrix whose only nonzero entry is $1$, $A_1=I_2$ and $A_2=A_0^t$, then $A_0+cA_1+c^2A_2$ is singular for all $c$, but $A_1$ is non-singular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result is false, here is a counter exemple :

Let $A_0,A_1,A_2$ as in your exemple. Consider $B_0,B_1,B_2\in\mathcal{M}_4(\mathbb{C})$ defined by block as follow:

$B_i=\begin{pmatrix}0_2&A_i\\0_2&0_2\end{pmatrix}$

where $0_2$ is the zero of $\mathcal{M}_2(\mathbb{C})$.

One easily check that the $B_i$ commutes and are nilpotent. Yet, as in your exemple $B(c)$ will have rank $1<\operatorname{rk}(B_2)=2$ for all $c$.

One can recover a positive result when A_0=0 (or r=1) by topological arguments :

The topology I will be considering is the Zariski topology.

First, note that for $0\leq k \leq n$ the set $r_k=\{X\in M_n(\mathbb{C})\mid \operatorname{rk}(X)\geq k\}\subset M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is open. Indeed, it is given by the fact that all $k\times k$ minors of $X$ (which are polynomials in the coefficient of $A$) are non zero.

Then, the map $\phi: c\mapsto A_1+cA_2+...c^nA_n$ is polynomial, hence continous. Therefore the sets $\phi^{-1}(r_k)$ are open in $\mathbb{C}$ for $0\leq k \leq n$.

Now, an open set in $\mathbb{C}$ is the complementary of the locus of the root of a polynomial $P\in\mathbb{C}[x]$. If $P\neq 0$ is has a finite number of roots. We deduce that if $\phi^{-1}(r_k)\neq\emptyset$, it is $\mathbb{C}$ minus a finite set of points. It is obviously non-empty in the case of $k=\operatorname{rk}(A_1)$ taking $c=0$.

Comment: Thank you for the counterexample. The second part is something that i knew. In fact, it's the positive result which led me to this `conjecture'!